# ASP.NET MVC Project halts and does not return the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, return

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 w/ Razor project with Entity Framework and .NET Framework 4

In my chtml View page, I have 2 BeginForms, one is to update account settings and the other is to create a new TTS voice file (text to speech). The first form calls my "Boxes" controller method and it works perfectly fine, it assigns the updated values into the Entity database.

The second BeginForm uses a simple text box where I would put in the text and it would direct to my second method within the same controller called "Boxes_TTS".

The method is called fine without any problems. I have my TTS code that takes in the string and processes it and then saves it to the entity. Here are the steps that my TTS Helper class performs when saving the file:

1) It gets the string of text

2) It Creates a a wave stream

3) Then it passes the wave stream to a method that converts it to VOX file (another type of a voice file). In this method it writes the wav file to disk, reads its and then converts it to vox, then reads it into the memory again.

4) Once the file was converted to vox and read into the memory, the method then writes the blob into the table within E.F.

5) Then it deletes both wav and vox files from the temp dir.

I cannot do this conversion in memory entirely, because the idea is not to hog the memory when the text is large and the TTS engine needs to do several processes at the same time.

In my controller, this is the code for the method that calls the TTS helper methods:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Boxes_TTS(BulletinBoardBoxesViewModel vm)
    {
        SetHttpContext(this.HttpContext);
        if (!IsIPAllowed)
            return new RedirectResult(@"~/Home/NotNow", true);

        var id = Session["RecordID"];
        if (id == null)
            return new RedirectResult(@"~/Home/Index", true);


        int? BoxID = (int?)Session["SelectedBBBoxID"];

        if (BoxID == 0)
            BoxID = null;

        vm.submitTTS((int)Session["RecordID"], (int)Session["CompanyID"], BoxID);

        ViewBag.SubmittedData = "Your TTS message has been made active.";

        return View("Boxes",vm);
    }
```

I stepped through the code and the return View("Boxes",vm); line is being executed but the View Boxes is never navigated to. Instead, the MVC site is halted and had an "busy" icon on my Internet Explorer page. After some time, the busy icon stops and when I try to navigate to another page within the site, it doesn't work, gives me null errors, etc. If I remove the vm.submitTTS() method, the return View works perfectly fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Yura

Comment: Is there code in the view itself that might be doing this?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but the view only contains references to the ViewModel and Forms, nothing else. I do not call the TTS method from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to create a new thread and put Microsoft's SpeechSynthesizer. Something about creating a new thread with SpeechSynthesizer helps the View render itself upon return. Async issue? Maybe. But it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is expected to return an "ActionResult" then I believe you need to return a ViewResult.

Comment: Returning a `View()` is an `ActionResult`.  If the types didn't match it would be a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Comment: I tried putting in ViewResult, I had to comment out the Redirect parts of the method because of errors. It compiled fine but still never redirected to the View. Can this occur due to file io that is happening locally? Although, the file io happens in a folder far away from the project folder. Can it be a synching issue between the TTS part and returning the view? Because like I mentioned before, if I comment out the TTS saving part, it returns the view just fine.

Comment: Ah, sorry - David's right. Can you get a return value from the TTS submission and assign it here (before moving on to the View)?

Comment: Inside the TTS helper class, I have the returned value entered into the Entity and then the returned ID is returned back to the view model (where tts helper was called from) and then inside the view model, the returned ID is also entered into the database via EF. I would like to have it separated like this. I tried putting the TTS code in the same class file as my view model, still, didnt work. It has to do something with the TTS method that causes this not to return a view. But the TTS code works fine, it does it's job, no errors.